# Display items from a List<CustomObject> in a List View in a metro app

Tags: listview, windows-8, microsoft-metro, listviewitem, .net-4.5

I have a List. It is populated with CustomObjects when a query is run on a database (and matching results are put into this List)

However, I then want to display each of the e.g. name properties of these resultant custom objects in a listview, this is the part that is causing me trouble.

Im unsure how to set up the template of the list view to display the data from the list. The furthest I have been able to get is as follows: If the result of the query has 3 matches, I can make 3 textboxes saying "HELLO" appear in the list view. This is achieved by putting a textbox saying "HELLO" in the template part of the listview (which is otherwise laid out as it is in the grid template of VS2012). Is the solution something to do with bindings?

Any help would be much appreciated. (working on a metro app, windows 8, .NET 4.5)

what I currently have looks something like this

```
List<CustomObject> CustObjList =... //gets matches from database
listView.ItemsSource = CustObjList;
```

then in the XAML is this

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>

      <UserControl Loaded="StartLayoutUpdates" Unloaded="StopLayoutUpdates">
           <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}" Grid.Row="1">
                <TextBlock x:Name="listViewText" Text="HELLO" <--(???) Margin="30,0,0,0" Foreground="Black"/>
```

Comment: Show us the code of what you tried (please just keep to the relevant parts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's bindings that you'll need.

Check out this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh780650%28v=win.10%29.aspx) about a variety of lists in Windows 8 XAML applications.

In particular, look at the `ItemTemplate`. Note how the `TextBlock`s are binding to properties of each object in the bound collection: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"`

```
<ListView x:Name="itemListView"
          Margin="120,0,0,60"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
          SelectionChanged="ItemListView_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="110" Margin="6">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="110" Height="110">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                </Border>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}" MaxHeight="60"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>          
</ListView>
```

Comment: I think the problem is that I don't know how to expose the property of my object so that I can reference it like "Description" is referenced in your example. how would I make this possible with my custom class?

Comment: sorry, the answer was right infront of me, I didn't realise I literally use the name of the property as defined in the class! many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are getting the data into the ListView, just not binding the properties correctly.  In the template where the textbox is, change the Text property on the TextBox to Text={Binding YourPropertyName"}.  This is a great article to help you get the basics down... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh780650(v=win.10).aspx

Comment: i think that's what my problem really is, working out which property I actually need to bind to the textblock. Im just having trouble understanding it. If I have a list of objects, each of which was a property called "name", what exactly have to do so that in the XAML I can type Text="{Binding name}"? Surely theres an intermediary step here that i'm missing that would allow the property to be exposed like this, or am I looking at it completely incorrectly?

Comment: It all gets down to binding context.  When you set the ItemsSource on the ListView, you have performed the intermediary step.  This binds the collection, represented by the itemsViewSource to the ListBox and it iterates over the items.  Now, if itemsViewSource is not the immediate collection, but has a collection property on it, like itemsViewSource.theItemList, then you would need to update the ItemsSource to reflect that - ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}, Path=theItemList}"  Once you get a collection into ItemSource, you reference the property in the binding